# add.import() adding some contents with my path

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, web, ember.js, ember-cli

I recently started on ember JS. 
I am trying to import bootstrap.css file from "node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css"

But when i run the server its shows error like
**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\For Saving\ember\project2\new_project\tmp\simple_concat-input_base_path-JBlVqJm6.tmp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css'**

It is adding some path with my path and giving me this error. I search a lot to solve this but i can't. And Also i installed the bower via npm and the bower_component is not getting added into my project folder.

Last thing I am not good with command Line Interface. can i run ember without terminal?
[image: Picture of the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `app.import` node modules files. It's only for `bower components` and `vendor` folder.

[Reference](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#compiling-assets) from ember-cli documentation.

Comment: how do i get the bower components in my project

Comment: First install bower through npm using `npm install -g bower` and install bootstrap using `bower install bootstrap`

Comment: yes i ran both the commands both are successful but bower_components didn't show up

Comment: Otherwise you can install  [ember-bootsrap](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap)